# CSS two column layout - Height 100% and width 100%

Tags: html, css

Check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uvk80oob/

```
.content {
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
bgcolor: #f8f4eb;
}

.sidebar{
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/S0I0UaN.png) repeat left top;
}
```

I am trying to make a simple layout for my personal use, and learning purposes. Having tried this for over three hours now, this is the closest I can get. I need the sidebar background image to be of 100% height. Also, I need the content width to be 100%.

Basically, the content div needs to be 100% at all times, and the sidebar background image could be fixed for all that matter. But it needs to be of 100% height.

Anyone who could point me in the right direction? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: try with absolute positioning

Comment: There are many tutorials, here is a [tutorial for 2-column and 3-column div blocks](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/uvk80oob/4/

...you can wrap the sidebar and content in a wrapper element and use:

```
.wrap {
  display:table;
  height:100%;
}

.wrap > div {
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
}
```